# Input file with names and popularity Java

Tags: java, arrays, fileinputstream

So I have a file that has names along with 11 popularity ranks which looks like [this](http://www.writeurl.com/text/2uu287wyl7rw9bls7y4q/mq34g5evmtu1f2y9x2yn). <--- (this is a link) I am a bit confused on what I am suppose to do with this next part that I have for my assignment. Generally I have a name app that looks like this:

```
public class Name{

private String givenName;
private int[] ranks = new int[11];

public Name(String name, int[] popularityRanks){
    givenName = name;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        ranks[i] = popularityRanks[i];
    }
}

public String getName(){
    return givenName;
}

public int getPop(int decade){
    if (decade >= 1 && decade <= 11){
        return ranks[decade];
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

public String getHistoLine(int decade){
    String histoLine = ranks[decade] + ": ";

    return histoLine;
}

public String getHistogram(){
    String histogram = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        histogram += ranks[i] + ": " + this.getHistoLine(i)
                + "\n";
    }

    return histogram;
}
}
```

It is not finished for the getHistoLine but that doesn't have anything to do with what I am trying to do. Generally I want to take these names in from the file and create an array of list.

How he describes it:

Create the array in main, pass it to the readNamesFile method and let that method fill it with Name objects

Test this, by printing out various names and their popularity rankings

For example, if main named the array, list, then upon return from the readNamesFile method do something like:

```
System.out.println( list[0].getName() + list[0].getPop(1) );
```

This is what my main looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class NameApp{

public static void main(String[] args){     

    Name list[] = new Name()

}

private static void loadFile(){
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    String fileName = "names.txt";

    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner (new File(fileName));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Error opening file named: " + fileName);
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
    }

    while (inputStream.hasNext()){

    }
}

}
```

I am just a bit confused how I can take the name have it send to the Name object list[] and then take the popularity ranks and send it to the Name object list[]. So when I call
    list[0].getName()

it will just call the name for one of the lines... Sorry I am a bit new to the java language. Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't correctly created a `Name` array. Should be something like this `Name list[] = new Name[someSize];`

Comment: From your file, did you want to create new `Name`s from every line in the file? And what is "popularity ranks"?

Comment: Yeah I think for my list[] array I want it to contain a name with the population for every name in the file. So like list[0].getName would give me A and list[0].getPop(1) would give me 140.

Comment: Is the name always just one letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `Name` list correctly. I would use a `List` since you don't know how many names there will be;

```
public static void main(String[] args){     

    List<Name> list = new ArrayList<Name>();

    loadFile();

    System.out.println(list.get(0).getPop());
}

private static void loadFile(){
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    String fileName = "names.txt";

    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner (new File(fileName));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Error opening file named: " + fileName);
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
    }

    while (inputStream.hasNext()){
        // givenName = something
        // ranks = something;

        list.add(new Name(givenName, ranks);
    }
}
```

Assuming each line is something like this (from your deleted comment)

```
A 1 234 22 43 543 32 344 32 43
```

Your while loop can be something like this

```
while (inputStream.hasNextLIne()){
     String line = inputStream.nextLine();
     String tokens = line.split("\\s+");

     String givenName = tokens[0];

     int[] numList = new int[tokens.lenth - 1];

     for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++){
         numList[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i].trim());
     }

     list.add(new Name(givenName, numList);
}
```

Comment: I actually figured it out... Should I post the solution on here so people can see it?

Comment: This answer actually has a minor defect: the list is defined and instantiated in `main()` but should either be passed in to `loadFile()` as a parameter or the variable should be a static member variable so `loadFile()` can access it (parameters are generally a cleaner approach).